# AndroidPublisher API 404s with "APK not found for the symbol file." when trying to upload Android App Bundle

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, android-app-bundle

I'm trying to use the [AndroidPublisher API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/) to upload app bundles from my CI server. So far, I've gotten everything setup and working except that after the bundle uploads (I'm seeing significant network traffic), I get this error message:

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "androidpublisher",
    "message" : "APK not found for the symbol file.",
    "reason" : "apkNotFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "APK not found for the symbol file."
}
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

This is the API I'm using: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/bundles/upload.

Oh, and something else I should mention is that manually uploading the aab using the console works just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any clue about your issue. But when you manually uploaded the aab on the console did you have a "Device support removed" warning?

Comment: Yeah, I did actually! I couldn't figure which devices died and why (I didn't bump my min SDK or anything). Anyway, why were you asking?

Comment: Because I have this warning too and I didn't bump min SDK and couldn't figure out why some devices are not supported anymore with aab. Now I know I'm not alone and maybe I should file a bug at least to have more detail about this.

Comment: Yeah, go for it! And please let me know what happens. 

Comment: It's reported there https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80002892